# install library in home directory

Tags: linux, installation, environment-variables

In Linux(Ubuntu) I am trying to run a tool and it is showing error "library missing". I don't have permission to install anything in the system (or simply sudo is not possible from my user account).
Is it possible to install missing library (libstdc++.so.6 in my case) in my home directory (without sudo) and change the environment-variables etc. so that all other tools/programs can find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, assuming the library is in `/home/user/lib`.  You can set use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to find the lib. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/lib`, which will find the library.  If you have to compile it yourself you will want to use `configure --prefix=/home/user`.

I'm surprised that `libstdc++.so.6` isn't available on the system already.  Take a look in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.  If could just be your program isn't multiarch aware.

Comment: I added export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib" in my .bashrc (because locate  libstdc++.so shows /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 ) but now I am getting error 'wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64' :(

Comment: Sounds like you have 32bit vs 64bit issues.  To discover the types of everything do "file libstdc++.so.6" and "file youprogram".  Also "uname -a".  That should show you what your system is and what the program is.  I'm guessing your program is a 32bit pre-compiled binary from somewhere.  It will probably be easiest to recompile it from source on the target machine.