# How to install a C++ library (such as Blitz++) in a specific directory (in one that doesn't require sudo privileges), on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, blitz++

I tried looking at some links on this site. The closest I found to my problem was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944271/install-library-in-home-directory) one, but still I wasn't able to solve my problem with it

I'm kind of new at this but basically, I intend to install the [Blitz++](https://github.com/blitzpp/blitz) library for C++, on Linux

Now, I've already done this once, by following the instructions of their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/blitzpp/blitz), where the following commands install Blitz++ on a Unix-like system:

```
mkdir build      # Inside the cloned Github repo
cd build
cmake ..
make lib
sudo make install
```

The only thing I'm trying to do here is avoiding using `sudo`. As far as I can understand, that command installs files and the library itself inside directories that need sudo privileges accept any modifications (correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not well-versed here). But say if I want to install the library in I directory for which I have permissions, in order to avoid having to use `sudo`?

How can I install said library in the home directory for instance, on Linux, without having to invoke `sudo`?

I know that for other C++ libraries, there is a `.configure` file inside their respective directories, and by typing something along the lines of `./configure --prefix=<directory_path>` (given that the current working directory is the library directory), it allows for the library to be installed in the specified path

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to do something similar with Blitz++, given that it has no `.configure` file whatsoever. Perhaps there is another way but I utterly lack knowledge in this area. Any help is appreciated.

---

Also, if anyone has any links or resources that help with understanding how C++ libraries work and how to generally install them, as well as any other recommended C++ resource, I'd appreciate if you let me know if it's not an inconvenience. Apologies for any mistakes and my ignorance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is CMake equivalent of 'configure --prefix=DIR && make all install '?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003374/what-is-cmake-equivalent-of-configure-prefix-dir-make-all-install)

Comment: Yes it does, plus it brings information about what I was failing to understand. Thanks a lot. This prompted me to learn more about CMake since I'm lacking in that area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a CMake question. Your looking for [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html). An example:

```sh
mkdir build      # Inside the cloned Github repo
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<directory_path> ..
make lib
make install
```